# HTML 5 Local Storage: If value = "..." do function

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have an on/off button and I'm trying to set it's value with html 5 localstorage.
On click, I added `localStorage.setItem("button", "On");`.

On document load: `localStorage.getItem("button");`

Now how can I say, **if localstorage.item("button") value = On**, do function. I'm using jQuery.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Umm, `if(localStorage.item("button") == "On") f();`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getItem` method returns the value. You invoke it whenever you need the value:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("button") == "On") ...
```

BTW, just calling `getItem` when the document is loaded serves no purpose.

Comment: Yeh I understood it just now. Give me a sec I tried this out.

Comment: So it's mostly how I thought it. Thanks alot sir. Can accept your answer in 5 mins